# Allocating and instantiating an object from a user controlled memory pool

Tags: c++, placement-new

- The C++ compiler I'm using is an older version (C++98 maybe?)
- I can NOT dynamically allocate memory from the system pool using things like new, malloc
- I can however use built-in OS calls to malloc from a heap array defined by me.

I'm running into some strange behavior (program crashes) when I do the following

```
class cBaseClass /* pure abstract */
{
public:
virtual void ifFunc( void ) = 0;
virtual ~cBaseClass() = 0;
}

inline cBaseClass::~cBaseClass()
{
}

class cDclass:cBaseClass
{
public:
cDclass();
~cDclass();
void ifFunc( void ); /* implement the pure virtual */
}

cDclass::cDclass( void )
{
printf("[0x%X] derived constructor called\n", this);
}
cDclass::~cDclass( void )
{
printf("[0x%X] derived destructor called\n", this);
}
void cDclass::ifFunc(void)
{
 printf("[0x%X] ifFunc called from derived class\n", this);
}

uchar_t myHeap[4096];

int main ( void )
{
   cDclass* pMyPtr = NULL;
    uint32_t i = 0;
    ( void ) memset( myHeap, 0, sizeof(myHeap)/sizeof(myHeap[0]);
   for( i = 0; i < 20; i++)
   {
       pMyPtr = myHeap[i * sizeof(cDclass) + 4];
       *pMyPtr = cDclass();
       pMyPtr->ifFunc(); /* Crash */        
   }
}
```

What I see is that the constructor for the derived class gets called..then its destructor gets called and then a crash.
Am I mistaken in believing that *pMyPtr = cDclass() constructs a class and then makes a copy of that class at the address specified by pMyPtr?
I say this because when I remove
pMyPtr = cDClass() 
and create a dummy variable to store an instance of cDclass and then use memmove it no longer crashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
*pMyPtr = cDclass();
```

Assumes that a valid object already exists at `*pMyPtr` and uses its assignment operator.  (On a typical implementation, this is probably not good enough because it doesn't copy the vptr.)

What you need instead is

```
new(pMyPtr) cDclass;
```

to call the constructor at a specified memory location.  You'll need to `#include <new>`.

Comment: I'm not sure you need to include `<new>` in order to use placement new.

Comment: @DavidHaim `<new>` is the only place the Standard specifies `operator new(size_t, void*)`.  And both g++ and clang++ complain if you try to use it without including any headers.

Answer (score 0):

The first weird thing is that this line:

```
pMyPtr = myHeap[i * sizeof(cDclass) + 4];
```

compiles without complaint. It's implicitly converting a `uchar_t` to a `cDclass*`, which shouldn't be possible without a `reinterpret_cast`. But it could be that your compiler is more lenient there. Anyway, at least you're missing a `&` operator here.

The second problem is that yes, you are wrong in your assumption. What the line does is construct a temporary object on the stack, then assume that at the pointer location there is already a fully constructed object, call that object's compiler-generated copy assignment operator with the temporary as an argument, then destroy the temporary.

The thing that never happens is that an object is actually constructed in the memory. This means the vptr is never initialized, so the call to the virtual function is a null dereference.

What you need to do is use *placement-new* to construct an object in-place. Your loop should look like this:

```
int main ( void )
{
    uint32_t i = 0;
    ( void ) memset( myHeap, 0, sizeof(myHeap)/sizeof(myHeap[0]);
    for( i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        // get the address to construct the object at
        uchar_t* pMyAddr = &myHeap[i * sizeof(cDclass) + 4];
        // construct a new object in-place at that address
        cDclass* pMyPtr = new (pMyAddr) cDclass();
        pMyPtr->ifFunc(); /* Don't crash */        
    }
}
```

Note that you will be responsible for actually calling the destructor for all the objects you created.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using placement-new? for example could I do cDClass temp = cDClass();  ( void ) memmove(pMyPtr, &temp, sizeof(temp));  Would this be the equiv of an in-placement new and perfectly safe to do? This is the approach I tried and it seems to work..but I'm not confident that it's completely safe. (What did people do before in-placement news were available?)

Comment: No, you can't. That's what placement-new is for. AFAIK it's been available pretty much since the beginning of C++, but early C++ had weird allocation and constructor semantics in general. Why do you want to avoid placement-new anyway?